# How to create react app using 'create-react-app' with specific expo version

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to create a react-native app with specific expo version.

npx create-react-native-app myApp

Comment: What have you tried so far? This sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65537734/979052

Comment: You don't create an expo app with `create-react-native-app`. Read the documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How create a react app with a specific version using the npx command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65537734/how-create-a-react-app-with-a-specific-version-using-the-npx-command)

Comment: i want a react-app only but some dependency are needed from expo with specific version

Comment: npx create-react-app --expo@43 my-app  is not working