# How to create a React project using an old version of Create React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I am learning react from an old tutorial, so I have to create a project with the version 1.5.2 of Create React App.
I have installed `create-react-app@1.5.2` globally with no problems.
After I executed `npx create-react-app` it uses the latest version of Create React App.

Is there any way that I could do it, or where can I find the code for a project with that version?

Comment: `npx create-react-app@1.5.2 ...`? But that's very old, why not find a newer tutorial?

Comment: If you update your question with the link to the tutorial we can probably find you a better one that uses the latest version of React.

Comment: Same question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65252602 ...

Answer (score 0):

It's no possible because of several reasons:

I installed the package "create-react-app@1.5.2" from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app/v/1.5.2) to assure I'm using the correct `create-react-app` version:

```
npm init -y
npm install create-react-app@1.5.2
    
or 

yarn init -y
yarn add create-react-app@1.5.2
```

In the `\node_modules\create-react-app` folder I executed the command:

```
node index.js app-folder
```

And it installed the last version of react without a template because it's an old version of the package, but still the latest version:

[image]

Checking the file `createReactApp.js` I can see it's meant to be that way, even if it's an old version of the builder "create-react-app" it will install the last version of the packages.

Also, if you try this command: `node index.js app-folder --scripts-version 1.5.2`

It will not found the version you want, instead, it will show a list of available versions of react-scripts.

[image]

According to the date, the correct packages are:

react: 16.4.2
react-dom: 16.4.2
react-scripts: 1.1.5

**So you can install the version you want with this:**

```
npm init -y
npm install react@16.4.2 react-dom@16.4.2 react-scripts@1.1.5

or

yarn init -y
yarn add react@16.4.2 react-dom@16.4.2 react-scripts@1.1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're react v18, and you want to go down to the previous non-change breaking version, here's what you can do:

In your **package.json** replace:

```
"react": "^18.0.0"
"react-dom": "^18.0.0"
```

With

```
"react": "^17.0.2"
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
```

Then go to your entry file **index.js** At the top, replace:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
```

With

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

In your **index.js** file, replace:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

With

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
   <App />
 </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

- Delete your node_modules and run yarn install or npm i --force
- After installation, run yarn start or npm start

**--------------------------------------OR------------------------**

If you want through npx command

```
npx create-react-app[version] my-app 
npx create-react-app@17.0.2 my-app
```